# Using a second table to determine the value of a cell in the first table

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with table 1 'city, country, region'.

On a separate tab there is table 2 'countries and regions'.

What statement can populate the 'region' column in table 1, based on the values in table 2?

**Table 1 - Cities and Countries**

```
+---+---------------+---------+--------+
|   |       A       |    B    |   C    |
+---+---------------+---------+--------+
| 1 | City          | Country | Region |
| 2 | New York      | USA     | ?      |
| 3 | San Francisco | USA     | ?      |
| 4 | London        | UK      | ?      |
+---+---------------+---------+--------+
```

**Table 2 - Countries and Regions**

```
+---+---------+-------------+
|   |    A    |      B      |
+---+---------+-------------+
| 1 | Country | Region      |
| 2 | USA     | US & Canada |
| 3 | France  | EMEA        |
| 4 | UK      | EMEA        |
+---+---------+-------------+
```

**Expected output (table 1 + regions)**

```
+---+---------------+---------+-------------+
|   |       A       |    B    |      C      |
+---+---------------+---------+-------------+
| 1 | City          | Country | Region      |
| 2 | New York      | USA     | US & Canada |
| 3 | San Francisco | USA     | US & Canada |
| 4 | London        | UK      | EMEA        |
+---+---------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Depends on the format of your data in the second sheet, but most likely it would be `vlookup`. An example would help, either in text or in a linked shared spreadsheet.

Comment: @Sally table example added to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used [Senseful's formatting tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to make these more readable.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en). Either in the one-cell form, copied down column C

```
=vlookup(B2, Table2!A$2:B, 2, false)
```

or in array form, where one command fills the entire column

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(filter(B2:B, len(B2:B)), Table2!A$2:B, 2, false))
```

In the second one, the array in column B is pre-filtered to avoid looking up any empty rows below the data.

The formulas assume that the second table is in sheet Table2; it could be anywhere else.